# Possible ways to determine reach of implicit lambda expressions

Tags: syntax, syntactic-sugar, lambda

When defining an inline function, even the shortest way to do so usually requires naming its argument (unless you're going for the point-free style and you have an expression that returns a function).

```
// JavaScript
arr.map(x => x + 1)

// Rust
iter.map(|x| x + 1)

// Haskell
map (\x -> x + 1) arr
```

In maths, this is called “arrow notation”, e.g. $x \mapsto x + 1$.

This is already short and sweet, especially when you compare it to things like `function (x) { return x + 1 }`. But can we do better?

An arguably less common way of defining functions in maths is using the “dot notation”, which looks like this: $(\;\cdot\;) + 1$. Interpunct (the middle dot) is a common choice, but it's not a necessary one -- any symbol used rarely enough would work. The idea is to avoid giving any specific “common” name to a function argument, and to instead pick an esoteric one and stick with it.

So I thought why not try this in a language.

```
arr.map(# + 1)
```

Researching, I've found out that Scala supports exactly this using `_`, and that Kotlin has something very similar using a reserved variable name `it`.

```
// Scala
list.map(_ + 1)
```

```
// Kotlin
list.map { it + 1 }
```

A glaring question that comes up is how do you know how far out the implicit lambda reaches, i.e. do the examples above desugar into `x -> list.map(x + 1)` or `list.map(x -> x + 1)`.

In Scala, desugaring happens up the syntax tree until the first pair of parentheses `()` is reached. In our case, that's the parenthesis for the function call, so the above snippet is what we intuitively expect.

In Kotlin, `{}` is used in general to denote lambdas. For example, you could rewrite the above as `list.map { x -> x + 1 }`. I'm not sure on the details, but apparently you can avoid writing the usual `()` parenthesis for function call if a lambda is the only argument to a function. So the full syntax sugar chain is `list.map({ x -> x + 1 })` as `list.map { x -> x + 1 }` as `list.map { it + 1 }`. So the scope is determined just like always: using `{}`.

This shows two ways to determine the reach of an implicit lambda.

Scala becomes tricky as soon as you have a more complex expression, where you want to use parentheses for grouping. Something as simple as `x -> 2 * (x + 1)` cannot be expressed using `2 * (_ + 1)` because it would inwind into `2 * (x -> x + 1)`, not `x -> 2 * (x + 1)`. Kotlin's approach seems better as there's a pre-established delimiter pair so this kind of thing doesn't happen. This also plays nicely with tiny additional shortcuts you can take like collapsing `({})` into just `{}`. The price is the additional `{}` you have to introduce *everywhere*, so instead of `val f = x -> x + 1`, you need `val f = { x -> x + 1 }` (which is not necessarily *bad*, but since we're talking about a first world problem anyway, it's worth pointing it out as a con).

What are other possible ways to determine the reach of a lambda expression, found in other programming languages (including non-mainstream ones)? What are their pros and cons?

Comment: Does this come down to: given a variable in an expression, assume this was introduced by a lambda such that the expression is in the body of the lambda expression - where would that lambda be? If so, I think this is a unique concept because we are used to the other way round: have constructs that introduce a binding and ask for its scope. I expect this to create challenging ergonomics.

Comment: @ChristianLindig Arguably, Kotlin's approach works the way you expect: `{...}` without `->` introduces a binding of `it`, which is then in scope within the braces.

Comment: Not the question, but might be helpful to think together: nested lambdas all using the special character(s)/token(s), as in `a.map(_ + sum(b.map(_ + 42)))`.

Comment: I'm not 100% on the grammatical details, but Mathematica uses a trailing `&` to close off that sort of inline lambda, for another data point. I think you could set operator precedence up so that a unary operator (suffix, in that case) had low precedence and would thus "grab" the right chunk of expression, a la `2 * (_ + 1)&` if the unary is lower precedence than the `*` you make the whole expression your lambda

Answer (score 2):

Here's one: integrate the parser and type-checker so that only **[token trees](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40303308)** (lexed tokens and parentheses groups) are initially parsed, then the compiler further parses outer expressions and type-checks them before parsing inner expressions.

When an expression gets parsed to a function call, the compiler will type-check the function and, whichever arguments are supposed to be closures, will be parsed as implicit closure expressions unless they are explicit (either start with `x ->` or identifiers which resolve to lambda expressions). When an expression gets parsed to the assignment, if the assigned-to identifier is a variable, the assigned value will be parsed as an implicit closure unless it's explicit.

Pros: this gives you maximum flexibility: you can create expressions like this, which aren't otherwise possible:

```scala
functionWhichTakesClosure(functionWhichTakesRegularArgument(_))
// Desugars to
functionWhichTakesClosure(x -> functionWhichTakesRegularArgument(x))


functionWhichTakesRegularArgument(functionWhichTakesClosure(_))
// Desugars to
functionWhichTakesRegularArgument(functionWhichTakesClosure(x -> x))
```

However, I'd say **this is a bad idea**. Because it creates a situation where the compiler is smarter than the developer, so that it generates code when it *should* throw a type error. What if someone changes `functionWhichTakesRegularArgument` so that it actually does take a closure (you know that in practice, functions won't have these obvious names)? What if `functionWhichTakesClosure` no longer takes a closure, the error message "`_` expression but none of the outer calls take a closure" isn't very helpful (or if one of the outer calls do take a closure, that will be even less helpful). Moreover, there are still ambiguities: what if `functionWhichTakesRegularArgument` takes a generic parameter, will it be inferred to a closure? You can resolve them (like say, generic types which can't be inferred will never be parsed as implicit closure, or just simplify so that even generics which *do* resolve to closure can't be parsed implicitly), but that only creates more complexity and confusion.

In this case, Scala's and Kotlin's simple solution (just desugar the inner-most parenthesis or braces into an implicit closure) is the best. Because it doesn't require type knowledge to understand; when the developer does mess up and pass an inner closure, they are breaking a simple rule, which is a lot easier to spot than breaking a more complicated one.